# How to contain this resizable div inside the outer div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a resizable and draggable box (grey in color). The box can be resized by stretching it from its corners.

I want to make sure that at any point, the inner grey box isn't able to be  dragged outside the outer yellow box. The edges of of the inner grey box should at max, touch the edges of the outer yellow box.

My code is here.
http://jsfiddle.net/akashdmukherjee/sa44ks9u/4/

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="outer" style="background-color: yellow; width: 600px; height: 400px; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 50px;">


        <div class="draggable_div rot">
            <div class="rotatable">
                <div id="inner" class="resizable" style="background-color: #3C3C3C; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>

  <div id="x_and_y_of_inner">Left: , Right: </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    $('.draggable_div').draggable();


    $( ".draggable_div" ).draggable({
      drag: function( event, ui ) {

        var left_most_cordinates = $("#outer").offset().left;
        var top_most_cordinates = $("#outer").offset().top;

        $("#x_and_y_of_inner").text( "Left: " + left_most_cordinates + " Top: " + top_most_cordinates );

        ui.position.left = Math.min( left_most_cordinates, ui.position.left );
        ui.position.top = Math.min( top_most_cordinates, ui.position.top );
      }
    });

    $('.resizable').resizable({
        aspectRatio: true,
        handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
    });



    $(document).on('mouseover', '.rot', function(){
        var tc = $(this);
        tc.rotatable({
            handle:tc.children('.rotate.left, .rotate.right')
        });
        return true;
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.draggable_div
{
    position: relative; 
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;   

    cursor: hand; 
    cursor: pointer;       
}

.resizable
{
    width: 50%;   
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;   
}
.resizable img
{
    width: 100%;   
}

.ui-resizable-handle 
{
    background: #f5dc58;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;

    z-index: 2;
}
.ui-resizable-se
{
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle 
{
    background: #f5dc58;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

    height:        10px;
    left:          50%;
    margin:        0 0 0 -5px;
    position:      absolute;
    top:           -5px;
    width:         10px;
}
.ui-rotatable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging
{
    visibility:  hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`containment`](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area)** property of `resizable` as below to make it containable inside its `parent`

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    containment:'#outer', //outer is the id of its root parent
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/sa44ks9u/7/)**

Comment: The fiddle link you shared doesn't really stop the box from going outside the yellow box. I get the point though.

Comment: It does buddy.. I don't give untested fiddle in my answer ever.. :) It does not allow your grey box from going outside the yellow box..

Comment: That's strange. For some, reason, it works differently, when I click it.
I also re-tried what you suggested on this fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4Vfm5/1894/
Didn't work. Can you see if this one works for you? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got your point now.. It doesn't work while **dragging** but works only on **resizing** right.. You need to add `containment` to `dragabble` too as you did for `resizable`.. Here is  **[your updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4Vfm5/1895/)** but am afraid the combination of dragabble and resizable would'nt get mingled together for all the scenarios.. :) you might need to find some other work around for this.. :)

Comment: Oh got it. Ya, it's like 95% perfect. Need to figure out a way to handle the strange behavior because of combination of draggable and resizable

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the options `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` accordingly. Both the options accepts the absolute values hence set values as `width` and `height` of `parent` element.

Try this:

```
$('.resizable').resizable({
  maxWidth: $('#outer').width(),
  maxHeight: $('#outer').height()
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/sa44ks9u/6/)